# H2 Update Multiple records

Tags: h2

I tried to run some updates on a table. Some are working, some are not.

**Update table1 set column 'bla' where column = 'haha'; --> Worked**

**Update table1 set column 'bla' where column = 'ha1'; --> IO Exception Permission denied (90031 - 200)**

I can't see why this should happen with this record, one worked the other not.

Please let me know if you have ever seen this error.

H2 1.4.200(2019-10-14) Spring Boot